# Problems when making a request with variable in apollo reactjs

Tags: reactjs, graph, typeerror, apollo-client, graphene-django

I am using graphene as backed and react on the front end with apollo but when trying to make a request where only one object returns, it gives me the following error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fitz7.png)

the code from react is

```
import React from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const Post = (props) => {

    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);

    const [loading, error, data] = useQuery(GET_POST, {
        variables: {
            postId: id
        }
    })

    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error}`;

    return (
        <div>
            Post
        </div>
    )
}


const GET_POST = gql`
query IdPost($postId: ID!){
    idPost(postId:$postId){
        id
        user{
            username
            email
        }
        title
        body
        image
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        published
    }
}
`;

export default Post
```

I do not know why it is really, here I also leave the code that I use in graphene for that request

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_posts = graphene.List(PostType)
    id_post = graphene.Field(PostType, postId=graphene.ID())

def resolve_all_posts(root, info):
    return Post.objects.filter(published=True)

def resolve_id_post(root, info, postId):
    return Post.objects.get(id=postId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is

```
const {loading, error, data} = useQuery
```

Not

```
const [loading, error, data] = useQuery
```

Comment: Yes I got confused but I still have an error

Comment: @FernandoLopez, you can provide us what is your React and Apollo Client version?